# values inside foreach pushes undefined?

Tags: reactjs, tsx

So I am working with a tsx file and I tried to push some html into a variable with options in it that takes their value from foreach item and so far so good but then I try to push them into some array and use it in my state in order to do the right thing for react it pushes undefined. ı am confused how it gives undefined when I try to push it into array and it gives value when I try to push it into html element

```
provider.getItems().then((items:any[]) => { 
        items.forEach((item) => {
            this.categoryOptItems.push(item.Title);
            this.categoryOpts.push(<option value={item.Title}>{item.Title}</option>)    
        })
        this.setState({categories: 
            this.categoryOptItems
        }) 
    })
```

Comment: do you mean a alist of undefineds?  did you try to add `console.log(item)` inside the loop to actually see what is in it?

Comment: yes it has my array but out of the brackets I can't reach it is gone I know this is some kind of javascript play but I couldn't find the way

Comment: check this documentation about `this` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: solved, after 2 days I encountered the same thing in different component and I had to do something about it then I realized that setState is takes it's time and the page is rendered before it is updated (I had messed code but it is okay now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution but not sure if it is the best way though.

This is in componentDidMount

```
    provider.getItems().then((items:any[]) => { 
        items.forEach((item) => {
            categoryOptItems.push(item.Title);
        })
        this.setState({categories: 
            categoryOptItems
        })
    })
```

This is the function

```
options() {
    var categories = this.state.categories;
    const html:any = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.categories.length; i++) {
        html.push(<option value={i+1}>{categories[i]}</option>);
    }
    return html;        
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but take out the forEach/push and change to map. It will be result in less code and be perform better. You can then move the logic out of your options function and put it directly inside your template.